# How do I add a space between two concatenated NSStrings?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, concatenation

I have three string objects:

```
NSString *firstName;
NSString *lastName;
NSString *fullName;
```

The values for `firstName` and `lastName` are received from NSTextFields.

I then want to concatenate the two strings and place the result in `fullname.`

This is the code that I'm using:

```
fullName = [firstName stringByAppendingString:lastName];
```

However, the result does not put a space between the two names (e.g. JohnSmith).

How do I add in the space? I'd like the result to look like (John Smith).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way is this:

```
fullname = [[firstName stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:lastName];
```

i.e. append the space, and then append the lastName.

Answer (score 14):

I'm amazed by the length of the other answers:

```
fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstname, lastname];
```

Comment: parsing a format specifier requires more work than a trivial string concatentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
fullName = [@[firstName, lastName]
             componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

That is normal. You will have to add the space yourself.

```
(NSString*) description { return [[[NSString alloc] 
                          initWithFormat:" %@ %@”, 
                          firstname, 
                          lastname] autorelease]; }
```